# Javascript convert date format from "yyyy-mm-dd" to "December 11th, 2013"?

Tags: javascript, function, date

How I make a sintax to convert date format from default format (yyyy-mm-dd) to english format like December 11th, 2013 using Javascript function?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str_date = "1983-24-12",
    arr_date = str_date.split('-'),
    months   = ['', 'January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

var new_date=months[arr_date[2]] + ' ' + arr_date[1] + ', ' + arr_date[0]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TN7NE/

#### Edit

You can add an ordinal using the following:

```
function addOrdinal(n) {
    var ord = [,'st','nd','rd'];
    var a = n%100;
    return n + (ord[a>20? a%10 :a] || 'th');
}
```

e.g.

```
addOrdinal(1); // 1st
```

Comment: but, "dd" also including e.g (1st, 2nd, 3th, 4th, ..., 11th, 12th) what's way that must I do?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

**Moment.js 2.7.0**

> Moment was designed to work both in the browser and in Node.JS.
>   Parse, validate, manipulate, and display dates in javascript.

and it is also available on [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/).

Comment: Yes, moment.js is the best for this. Also if you use angular, you can use a directive: https://github.com/urish/angular-moment

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function like this:

```
function formatDate(date) {
  months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
            'May', 'June', 'July', 'August',
            'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
  dateSplit = date.split('-');
  year = dateSplit[0];
  month = months[parseInt(dateSplit[1]) - 1];
  day = parseInt(dateSplit[2]);
  switch(day) {
    case 1:
    case 21:
    case 31:
      day += 'st';
      break;
    case 2:
    case 22:
      day += 'nd';
      break;
    case 3:
    case 23:
      day += 'rd';
      break;
    default:
      day += 'th';
  }
  return month + ' ' + day + ', ' + year;
}
```

Comment: Adding an ordinal can be much simpler (and your function fails with 21, 22, 23 and 31).

Comment: I've fixed that cases. And RobG is right: the function addOrdinal in other answer is more elegant.